# What will be changed if prebuild in React Native Expo Poject?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-fbsdk-next

I want to use `react-native-fbsdk-next` in Expo project (Expo SDK 46)

https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next

The package doesn't support `expo install`, so I have to use `npx expo prebuild` to release iOS and Android folder.

But as the doc says:

https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/

```
Your app can still run in Expo Go, however, any custom native code won't be accessible if it's not already present in the Expo Go app.
```

So I guess it still can type `expo start` to run the app, but my question is:

1. Is it still can publish the app by `eas build` ?
2. If I release Android and iOS folder manage by myself, is it still can use `expo upgrade` to upgrade the Expo SDK ?